# Passar um parâmetro GET através da view em Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

eu estou tentando passar um parâmetro via GET na URL através do backend do Django, porém não estou conseguindo isso.

Minha url para a página que eu quero passar o parâmetro é

```
url(r'^(?P<short_name>\w+)/schedule/$', schedule_views.schedule, name='schedule'),
```

E eu queria que, logo após eu fazer as coisas na view chamada, ele renderizasse a página com o link schedule/?date=2018-03-01, por exemplo.

Eu sei que consigo pegar o GET através do request.GET.get, porém eu gostaria de passar esse parâmetro de volta para o front-end.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que a solução seria você fazer o redirect já com a query string, algo como:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def schedule(request):

    # varios codigos

    return redirect(reverse('search_view') + '?date=2018-03-01')
```

Comment: Aí na 'search_view' eu teria que colocar um argumento para poder receber a date?

Comment: Aí vai depender de onde realmente você quer pegar esse date.

Comment: Eu consegui usar utilizando variáveis de seção! Obrigado!

Comment: Show! Se a resposta tiver sido correta pra resolver o problema, pode marcar ela como correta? Assim outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema vão conseguir achar mais facilmente :)